# Codeigniter 2 Routing with undeterminded number of segments/parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, ion-auth

I am using Codeigniter 2 and am currently using the 'Routers' config file to set the routes.
I am also using IonAuth library. 
I have a code that does something like:

```
    $route['admin/(login|logout|change_password|forgot_password|reset_password
|activate|deactivate|create_user)'] = "auth/$1";
```

Now  my problem is that, in some of the IonAuth methods, there are none, 1 or 2 parameters.
If I try to access the url like:

```
http://localhost/ion_auth_try/admin/deactivate/1
```

I get an 404 error.

The signature of the 'deactivate' method is

```
function deactivate($id = NULL)
```

I've been trying to solve this for a long time now. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I'd do this instead.

```
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "auth/$1";
```

It's much more simpler and it solves the problem perfectly. With the above rule, you can access both `admin/some_method` and `admin/some_other_method/with_a_parameter` just fine. However, you should note that if you were to access the page by entering just `admin`, you'd need to add the following:

```
$route['admin'] = "auth";
```

See the doc: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: Here's my problem:
Let's say I have code that says <br/>

$route['admin/deactivate/(:num)'] = "auth/$1"; <br/>
And I want to access 'admin/deactivate/' I can't.

Comment: Have you actually tried changing it to `$route['admin/(:any)'] = "auth/$1";` ?

Comment: Yes, I have.
I guess the only way to do this would be writing numerous Routes configs. I was wondering if there's a way to avoid or maybe use some regular expression to dynamically match that.

Comment: Also I am not doing $route['admin/(:any)'] = "auth/$1"; because I already have a admin controller. I want the above specific requests to redirect to go to auth controller and rest would go to admin controller.